# Fails to load a default profile when starting a spring-boot application

Tags: spring-boot

I have `application.yml` file with spring profiles defined as follows:

```yml
spring:
  profiles:
    include:
      - dev
      - prod
  application:
    name: my-app-name
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
...
```

and `application-prod.yml` file:

```yml
...
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: production-kafka-bootstrap:9092
...
```

When I start the app with `mvn spring-boot:run`, it fails with:

```
...
The following profiles are active: default,prod
...
ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values:

bootstrap.servers = [production-kafka-bootstrap:9092]
...
Couldn't resolve server production-kafka-bootstrap:9092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for production-kafka-bootstrap
...
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
...
```

It seems like Spring loads the value from the `application-prod.yml` file instead of the default,  `application.yml`. What am I missing?

Comment: what happens if you remove `- prod` from `application.yml`?

Comment: What for? I need it to keep production values.

Comment: I mean what happens if you remove `- prod` from `spring: profiles: include:` in file `application.yml` since from my understanding of the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-adding-active-profiles) "`spring.profiles.include` property can be used to unconditionally add active profiles", so when the app runs it loads values from default (`application.yml`) and prod (`application-prod.yml`) because `- prod` is specified in `spring.profiles.include`

Comment: It is weird and still unclear for me how to separate profile specific values into `application-{profile}.yml` file. If I remove `prod` entry from `application.yml`, the app starts using default values from `application.yml`. If I pass in `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=prod` it DOES NOT take `prod`values. What's wrong with that?

Comment: `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod` works when you run the app from a `.jar`, e.g: `java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar app.jar`. it can't be used directly when you start the app from the maven plugin. you should use `-Dspring-boot.run.profiles=prod`, e.g: `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=prod`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out how to achieve that (with the help of @MarcoLucidi).
You don't need to specify profiles in any `application.yml` files (no matter, dev, prod, etc.). If you want to pass in an active profile, you will have to:

- build your app with `mvn clean install -DskipTests`;
- run it with `java -jar ./target/spring-demo-0.0.1.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod`(the name of your jar file will be different);
- check the Terminal for output results, it should contain something like this:

```
Starting SpringDemoApplication v0.0.1...
The following profiles are active: prod
...
```